# Files are not selectable on Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to attach a text file of any format in my app. So i have written the following code. The problem is that, i cannot select files from any folder. But if go through any file manager (e.g : ES file explorer), i can access those files. I have also attached screenshot please see that to get clear idea.

[image: Files are greyed out in downloads folder]

[image: Files are selectable when opened via file manager]

Below is the code i have used.

```
void pickDocument() {

        Intent documentIntent;

        documentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        documentIntent.setType("text/*");

        startActivityForResult(documentIntent, PICK_DOCUMENTS);
}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {

            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
                return;

            switch (requestCode) {

                case PICK_DOCUMENTS:

                    Uri documentUri = data.getData();

                    if (mChooseFileDialogListener != null) {

                        mChooseFileDialogListener.onDocumentClick(documentUri, ViewModel.FILE_TYPE);

                    }

                    break;

            }

        } 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Replacing

```
 documentIntent.setType("text/*");
```

with

```
documentIntent.setType("*/*");
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Now the files are clickable, but images, videos and audio files are also visible. I just want to display documents. So user should be able to select only document files.

Comment: did you get any answer file not selectable for specific  mime type(not all */*) @Harshith ?